# How to escape second tier html quotes in a php echo?

Tags: php, jquery, html, syntax, jquery-selectors

I cannot find a way to escape second tier html quotes in a php echo:

```
PHP 
echo "<div id='myDiv'></div>
<select onchange='myfunction(this,"#myDiv")'>
options and such 
</select>
";
```

It seems the escape has to apply to not only php but also to html for them to work.
I even tried to save the second argument to myfunction as a php variable and passing it in the echo but then jquery didn't accept this. .. or maybe I just did it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this:

```
   echo '<div id="myDiv"></div>
          <select onchange="myfunction(this,\'#myDiv\')">
              options and such 
          </select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the quotes using a backslash. This should work now:

```
echo "<div id='myDiv'></div>
<select onchange='myfunction(this,\"#myDiv\")'>
options and such 
</select>
";
```

It should be echoing:

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<select onchange='myfunction(this,"#myDiv")'>
options and such 
</select>
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you but I tried this one and it worked to the PHP ... but when the code runs and the echo becomes html in the DOM, the backslash is read as a character not as an escape.

Comment: @KyleM I've tried it in Chrome too, the code should be working :)

Comment: The page is more complicated, I am not sure what I am missing, obviously this is only an example.  Thank you much ... I found that using the opposite quotes as @Supun had shown made it work. Thank you both.